# java.sql.SQLException: other error: request outdated while connecting to TIDB from Spark using mysql-connector-java 5.1.6 connector

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, mysql-connector, tidb

Getting the following error while connecting to `TIDB` through `Spark` using `mysql-connector-java 5.1.6 connector`.

Please note, I have created jdbc connection using the parallel connections option, where we specify the column name, lower bound, upper bound and the number of partitions.

Spark then breaks it into (number of partitions) queries, by dividing the lower bound and upper bound of the column name into equal sizes.

```
java.sql.SQLException: other error: request outdated.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:1551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:474)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2554)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1755)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2165)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2086)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2237)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1092)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:809)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`other error: request outdated.` is an error thrown by `TiKV`, which indicates the query exceeds the timeout limit `end-point-request-max-handle-duration` before executing, and canceled by coprocessor to avoid staled query. You may configure it in TiKV's config, its default value is 60 seconds.

Since Spark retrieves this error from JDBC, it means that the requests are too heavy for `TiDB` to handle so that some requests waited too long. That is mainly because Spark splits requests for each partition, resulting in heavy workload for TiDB. It makes matter worse while you are using parallel connection.

As a matter of fact, [TiSpark](https://github.com/pingcap/tispark) is developed to be a solution for querying with Spark along with TiDB. It now supports Spark 2.1 and will support Spark 2.3 in a few days. Try it!